# Can a NetMQ router socket (server) detect if a req socket (client) has reached a timeout?

Tags: c#, netmq

I am using NetMQ v3.3.3.4 to develop a simple server(RouterSocket) - client(RequestSocket) scenario. It works as expected except for one thing.

Sometimes the server takes too long to return a response and the client reaches a timeout. This behavior is desired. The issue here is that the server does not detect that the client is already gone and it continues processing the request. At some point the processing is done and the server tries to return a response. The server never realizes that the client is not listening  anymore and thinks that a response has been successfully delivered. This leads to a misleading user feedback and wrong log file entries.

Is it possible for the server to detect if a client is still waiting for a response?

Server

```cs
        private void Listen()
        {
            using (var poller = new NetMQPoller())
            using (var responseSocket = new RouterSocket())
            using (var poisonedSocket = new ResponseSocket())
            {
                responseSocket.Bind(_bindServerString);
                poisonedSocket.Bind(_bindTerminationString);

                var keepAliveTimer = new NetMQTimer(KeepAliveInterval);
                keepAliveTimer.Elapsed += (s, a) =>
                {
                    _monitorPublisher.Status["KeepAlive"] = Application.LocalDateTime.Now.ToString();
                    _monitorPublisher.SendStatus();
                };

                poisonedSocket.ReceiveReady += (s, a) =>
                {
                    a.Socket.ReceiveFrameBytes();
                    poller.Stop();
                };

                responseSocket.ReceiveReady += (s, a) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bool header = true;
                        byte[] response = null;
                        while (a.Socket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(out byte[] message))
                        {
                            // Using a ROUTER socket...
                            if (header)
                            {
                                // We have to first, wait for the first frame,
                                // which is the address (header) of the REQ socket.
                                // Afterwards, we have to wait for the second frame,
                                // which is 0 and act as a delimiter between the REQ address
                                // and the actual body of the request.
                                a.Socket.SendFrame(message, true);

                                // Once we have the header delimiter, we can be sure that
                                // the next frame is the actual request.
                                header = !(message.Length == 0);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Parse the request and return a response
                                BridgeRequestReceived?.Invoke(message, out response);
                                a.Socket.SendFrame(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logger.Instance.Log(e);
                    }
                };

                poller.Add(keepAliveTimer);
                poller.Add(responseSocket);
                poller.Add(poisonedSocket);

                Logger.Instance.Log($"Receiving requests on: {_bindServerString}", Application.LogCategory.Info);
                poller.Run();

                responseSocket.Close();
                poisonedSocket.Close();
            }
        }
```

Client

```cs
        private string SendRequest(IBridgeMessage request, out Exception e)
        {
            e = null;
            string response = null;
            using (var socket = new RequestSocket())
            {
                try
                {
                    socket.Connect(_endpoint);
                    byte[] encryptedRequest = CryptoAES.StandardCrypto.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NMTBridgeMessageFactory.Serialize(request)));

                    socket.SendFrame(encryptedRequest);
                    if (socket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(_timeout, out byte[] reply))
                    {
                        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(CryptoAES.StandardCrypto.Decrypt(reply));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e = new TimeoutException("Timeout occured!");
                        response = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    e = ex;
                    response = null;
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
```

I expect the server detects a client disconnection.

Comment: YBy default router silently ingorevsend for dead peer. You can use the mandatory option, which will throw exception if the peer is dead, which you can catch and log correctly.

Comment: You can also send the client timeout as part of the request, that why the server will know when to stop processing.